# What is the remainder when $12^{39} + 14^{39}$ is divided by $676$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I tried following but then I got stuck

$676 = 26*26$

$12^{39} + 14^{39}$ is divisible $26$ for sure since $a^n + b^n$ is divisible by $(a+b)$ when $n$ is odd. But what to do next?

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) and some other questions posted there among listed questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $$12^{39}+14^{39}$$  is divisible by $4$

Again, $$12^{39}=(13-1)^{39}\equiv-1+\binom{39}113\pmod{169}\equiv-1$$

$$14^{39}=(13+1)^{39}\equiv1+\binom{39}113\pmod{169}\equiv1$$

More generally if $\displaystyle a\equiv b\pmod p, a^p\equiv b^p\pmod{p^2}$

Here $\displaystyle p=13,12\equiv-1\pmod{13}\implies12^3\equiv(-1)^3\equiv-1$

Similarly, $\displaystyle14\equiv1\pmod{13}\implies14^3\equiv(1)^3$

Comment: Could you please elaborate the second part How (mod 169) is 0?

Comment: @user3710832, Have you understood how $12^{39}\equiv-1\pmod{169}?$

Comment: No. Please elaborate a little.

Comment: @user3710832, Do you understand binomial theorem ?

Comment: Yes. But how is that applied here?

Comment: @user3710832, $$(13-1)^{39}=13^{39}+\cdots+\binom{39}113-1\equiv39\cdot13-1\equiv-1\pmod{169}$$ as the other terms contain higher powers of $13,$ hence divisible by $169=13^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left((39-12)^{39}+(39-14)^{39}\right) \div 26 \times 26$$
so $$\left(27^{39}+25^{39}\right) \div 26$$
so $$1^{39}+(-1)^{39}$$

Comment: Please explain first step. Thanks!